# Simple VB.NET RegularExpressionValidator not working

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I'm embarrassed to ask but I've been at this for hours trying multiple solutions with no luck.

I'm trying to validate the file name used by my asp.net **FileUploadControl**.

All I want to do is test if the file starts with "RFTrack".

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" MaxLength="75" runat="server" CssClass="input" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"
  ErrorMessage="Must start with 'RFTrack'" ValidationExpression ="^rftrack"
  ControlToValidate="FileUploadControl" >
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Using this validation, I can not get any test files starting with "RFTrack" to pass the validation. I have even tried using a file just named "rftrack" to no avail.

I used multiple online Regex testers that have confirmed that my regex is correct. I have also tried things like

```
 ^(rftrack|RFTRACK)
```

With no luck. I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: Try `(?i)^rftrack`. If it does not work you just need to provide upper and lowercase letters for each: `^[rR][fF][tT][rR][aA][cC][kK]`.

Comment: You probably need to add `.*` to the end of the regex, and maybe get rid of the `^`.  Regex-based validator controls usually anchor the match at both ends automatically.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions but after implementing each of them,  it is still not working. Which is strange because I can validate the end of a file name just fine with `^.+(.zip|.ZIP)$`.